# How to share Contact Record without linking Account Record

Tags: sharing, owd

I have few `Contact` Record and I want to `share` it with other `Groups`. I have set the `Contact Sharing rule` and also set the `Object level access for the profile.`

Thing is, I am able to `share Contact Record` successfully, if `Contact` record is linked with an `Account` Record. But, if we are not linking any `Account` Record, then I am not able to `share` the  `Contact` record.

Can it be possible to `share` a `contact` Record without linking an `Account`.

FYI : `Contacts's OWD is Private and  Account's Public Read/Write`

Comment: Do you mean you must have an account associated with a contact for your sharing to work?

Answer (score 5):

Contacts without Accounts are called "private contacts". 
Contacts have a special hybrid relationship with the Account(has characteristics of both lookup and master-detail relationships)l .

To answer your question, sharing rules do not apply to "private contacts". The sharing will be "private" irrespective of the sharing rules defined on the contact.

Also you cannot do manual sharing on private contacts.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004005&language=en_US

To get around this limitation, you could have a dummy/generic account to assign to such contacts.